# Как работать с cmd в C#?

Tags: c#, cmd

А вот и сам код, из-за которого я не пойму, почему он не работает:

```
Process cmd = new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"del d:\1.txt");
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Запускается, а вот файл не удаляет, мерцанием появляется и исчезает, так ничего и не сделал.

Вот с Try catch оберткой :

```
try
{
    Process cmd = new Process();

    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"del D:\1.txt");
    cmd.WaitForExit();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка кода");
}
```

Но и так тоже не работает.

Окно cmd быстро появляется и исчезает и ничего, главное, не делает, а ошибок в коде нет.

Мне кажется, не удаляет файл из-за того, что выполняется код слишком быстро, что он не успевает удалить файл. Есть ли у кого идея, как нибудь сделать Delay в коде?

Comment: pause добавьте после del, окошко и не закроется.

Comment: сейчас попробую так сделать

Comment: а нету другого способа кодом управлять cmd.exe ?

Comment: Могу предположить, что в конце передаваемого cmd.exe текста надо добавить \\r\\n (или просто \\n ?)

Comment: а если мне нужно выполнить не одну а несколько команд ?

Comment: Думаю, что каждую передаваемую строку надо завершать \\r\\n. Последняя строка "exit\\r\\n".

По сути Вы эмулируете ввод с клавиатуры для cmd.exe .

P.S.

С C# не знаком, на C через popen() делал бы так.

Comment: попробую , а вообще я бы с легкостью на AutoIT сделал но я не хочу так смешивать код AutoIT и C# это бы выглядило как извращенство

Comment: Окно cmd быстро появляется и исчезает и ничего главное не делает

Comment: @amrwide, извините, с cmd.exe я что-то напутал. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: Да нет, не напутал. В C все работает, как сначала написал. Это, конечно, не ответ на Ваш вопрос, но кину код на С. Может окажется чем-то полезно.

Comment: по-моему, отличный способ выражения благодарности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, конечно, не ответ на Ваш вопрос,  код на С. Может окажется чем-то полезно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main ()
{
  printf ("Hello\n");
  FILE *out = popen("cmd.exe","w");
  if (!out) {
    perror("popen");
    exit (1);
  }
  fputs("dir xaxa\r\ndel xaxa\r\ndir xaxa\r\n",out); fflush(out);
  pclose(out);
  printf ("Bye\n");
}
```

Но !!! Никакого окна **не возникает**. Просто в окне командной строки, откуда запускаем эту программу, выводится

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Версия 5.1.2600]
(С) Корпорация Майкрософт, 1985-2001.

c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>dir xaxa
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 18BD-9283

 Содержимое папки c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode

11.04.2012  18:27                10 xaxa
               1 файлов             10 байт
               0 папок  193 600 765 952 байт свободно

c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>del xaxa

c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>dir xaxa
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 18BD-9283

 Содержимое папки c:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode

Файл не найден
```

Comment: Спасибо за содействие, я нашел истину ответа:
`Process.Start(@"D:\Documents and Settings\hashcode\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe", "install application.apk");`

Answer (score 1):

Приложение консольное?

`cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` попробуйте поставить в false. У меня так сработало.

Comment: всеравно не работает

Comment: Ну, могу только посоветовать обернуть это в try-catch + пошаговая отладка.

Comment: приложение WinForms

Comment: аааа, WinForms, это всё меняет, тогда обернуть это в try-catch + пошаговая отладка

Comment: сейчас проверим

Comment: неработает !