# Работа с командной строкой C#

Tags: c#, .net, командная-строка

<s>**Первое** Проблема</s>

<s>Я создаю процесс `var process = new Process()`. Задаю ему `FileName = "cmd.exe"; StartInfo.RedirectStandartInput = true;`, запускаю его и пишу `process.StandartInput.WriteLine(команда)`. Открывается командная строка и там несколько строк `Неверный дескриптор.` С чем это может быть связано?</s>

<s>**Второе** Задача</s>

<s>Когда неверный дескриптор подчинится, я бы хотел сразу задать вопрос по поводу реализации чтения результата. Мне нужно, чтобы синхронно выполнялись команды, и после выполнения записывался результат. Что-то типо
process.StandartInput.WriteLine("Команда 1");</s>

<s>list.Add(process.StandartOutput.ReadLine()); //Только надо читать не строку, а весь результат
process.StandartInput.WriteLine("Команда 2");
...</s>

<s>**Дополнение было удалено**</s>

**Запуск самого исполняемого файла** Без использования командной строки

Благодаря комментаторам, стал вызывать не командную строку, а сам exe файл. У меня получилось вызвать его, но я не могу прочитать результат. Как это сделать теперь мой единственный вопрос

```
//Создаём процесс
var process = new Process();

//Задаём исполняемый файл
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"adb.exe";

//Перехватываем вывод
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

//Выполняем(открывается командная строка, выдаёт результат(а именно справку по adb) и после закрывается. Что программа выполняется я уверен, теперь надо получить результат) 
process.Start();

//Пытаюсь получить результат, но возвращает null
var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Вопрос неполный. Попробуйте на известных всем командах показать такой пример, который легко можно каждому повторить. Покажите не три строчки, а весь механизм "перехвата" ввода вывода, возможно вы при перехвате допустили ошибку.

Comment: это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99505/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-cmd-%D0%B2-c-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-avp читали?

Comment: Нет, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, привёл пример

Comment: У вас ошибка при ReadLine (неверный дескрипотр)? Строка `if(result)` для c# не соберётся, это не `с++`, для c# лучше `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))`

Comment: Вместо *Я создаю процесс... Задаю ему...* и тп приведите нормальный сниппет кода и прокомментируйте его. В таком виде это плохо читаемо

Comment: Вам уже написали выше - оставьте в тексте один вопрос, с минимальным примером для воспроизведения. Не общим "Я создаю процесс var process = new Process()", не планами на "вот это я буду делать когда проблему решу", а куском кода, который каждый может себе скопировать и запустить.

Comment: Кстати, вы же можете просто запустить adb отдельным процессом, с указанием стартового каталога и параметров. Через тот же Process.Start. Зачем вам промежуточные проблемы в виде cmd?

Comment: А ведь это хорошая идея. Можно запустить adb.exe и передать ему аргументы, но разве Process.Start вернёт результат?

Comment: @Morkoffka нет adb под рукой, но он может писать справку не в output, а в error - тогда вы будете получать пустой текст из StandardOutput. попробуйте перенаправить и почитать StandardError.